# 'Toolkit not initialized' exception when unit-testing an JavaFX application

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx-8

When I try to perform unit tests on components which contain JavaFX controls I get a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Toolkit not initialized`.

How can components be unit tested which operate with JavaFX controls?

Comment: They need to run on the FX Thread - have you looked at TestFX?

Comment: @purringpigeon Not yet, never heard about it - but now I will, thanks for the hint!

Comment: @purringpigeon Does TestFX integrate with JUnit?

Comment: I think so but I don't use it. It was pretty cumbersome to use. We settled on QFTest which is a click  through ui to record scripts. Its easy fast and reliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.saxsys</groupId>
  <artifactId>jfx-testrunner</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and the following annotation to your test classes

```
@RunWith(JfxRunner.class)
```

Comment: @g Thanks, that helped a lot :-)

Answer (score 12):

Just declare and initialize a [JFX Panel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html). Like:

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    [.. Begin tests ..]
}
```

It is the easy way...

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution. It required the maven dependency: groupid org.openjfx, artifactId javafx-swing.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @multiplayer1080 answer but more elegant...

```java
import javafx.application.Platform

@BeforeAll
static void initJfxRuntime() {
    Platform.startup(() -> {});
}
```

You can go further and declare an abstract class with this method like that:

```java
abstract class FXTest {
    @BeforeAll
    static void initJfxRuntime() {
        Platform.startup(() -> {});
    }
}
```

and then inherit it when you test JavaFX runtime required stuff:

```java
class SomeGuiTest extends FXTest {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It says not on FX application thread.

Comment: I'm sorry, did work for me

Comment: For me it works, but it produces following warning into console: `WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @51c8530f'`

Comment: @Ellrohir the warning is because you use the classpath, it's harmless